# How to Execute Build command in jenkins(Ubuntu)

Tags: command-line, java, jenkins, selenium

I need to integrate a simple selenium script with Jenkins. Can someone please help me to get a shell script code to update in the build section.

Currently, I am tried with run.bat file which returns the following error.

```
Building in workspace /home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo [JenkinsDemo] $ cmd /c call /tmp/jenkins2455301809650179322.bat FATAL: command execution failed java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/home/mythos/loremine/Automation_Workspace/JenkinsDemo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427) Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not provided the command anywhere. The only code updated is `Java –cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testNg.xml` in run.bat file

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way:

Save your Program/Script in a Source Code Repository (Github,
Gitlab, Bitbucket, .....)

Create New Build Job
In Source Code Mgmt,

Give Source Code Repository & Login Details

In Build Section, give list of commands to execute your Program/Script (Since you mention Java, I
assume it would be   javac .java  java

In Post Build  Actions, Add your Email ID, to get Email
Notifications...

This is the minimal setup you need.

Once you get comfortable, Pl note, ..
Each of the above can be parameterized,